# Adding .cls to portable MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, document-classes

I guess specifically it would help to know where the texmf path is. I make extensive use of a particular class and need to add it to MiKTeX portable. Can someone point me in the right direction? I saw the post about adding a custom `.sty` file; do I need to do something comparable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kept getting an error stating a non-TDS compliant root when trying to add my local texmf tree. These are the steps that I had to work through to get it working:

1. *Create the root directory:* Say f: is the drive with portable MiKTeX. Create **f:\Local TeX Files**
2. *Create the subdirectory:* **f:\Local Tex Files\tex\latex\misc** and copy your *.sty and *.cls files here.
3. *Register the root directory:* Go to MiKTeX options, click on Roots, and add the root directory containing the subdirectory.
4. *Update FNDB:* Go to MiKTeX options and click **Refresh FNDB**.

This should have you up and running.

Comment: FYI: I followed the advice of this page http://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html

Answer (score 9):

You should never manipulate the standard texmf tree of portable MiKTeX. Create and use instead a local TeXMF tree.

Let drive `f:` be the drive with your portable MiKTeX. Now create a new directory like `f:\local-texmf`.  Now you can create inside it new folders depending on what you want to use. Let's say you want to use a class `miracle`.  Then create the folder `f:\local-texmf\tex\latex\miracle` and include there the `sty` or `cls` file.

Now open the settings of portable MiKTeX and add your `local-texmf` tree with a right-click in the taskbar on the MiKTeX symbol, choose "MiKTeX-Options", click on "Roots" and add there your `local-texfm` tree. Don't forget to update your FNDB ... .

Comment: When you say to open the setting of portal MiKTeX and add the local tree, do you mean under the "Paths for TeX and related programs" after going to Edit-> Preferences-> Typesetting? I did this and I am having no luck.

Comment: Or do you mean MiKTeX options from the taskbar panel?